How to get return value of Invoke-Expression in Powershell
So this is my code
$result = Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath $ps1

How do I get the result given by $ps1?
The code of that function is supposed to give a true false result like in the following:
function MyFunction{
#some code
if ($JobStatus -like "Running")
        {
        $result = $false
            Write-Host "Gresit" -foreground Red
        }
    else 
        {
        $result = $true
            Write-Host "Corect" -foreground Green
        }
return $result
}

I added this command and unfortunately I have red output
if ( $result -eq $null ) { write-host "Result: $result" -foreground Red } 


Instead of Write-Host, use return.
Ex:
if ($JobStatus -like "Running")
        {
        $result = $false
            return "Gresit"
        }
    else 
        {
        $result = $true
            return "Corect"
        }
}

Or:
if ($JobStatus -like "Running")
    {
    $result = $false
        $returnValue = "Gresit"
    }
else 
    {
    $result = $true
        $returnValue = "Corect"
    }
}
return $returnValue


I edited my code, in the original version I had the return $result which I forgot to add in my question code.

the first $result = Invoke-Command ... returns nothing. it is null

if ( $result -eq $null ) { write-host "Result: $result" -foreground Red } I added this command and unfortunately I have red output

Strange, it works fine when i try it myself.
Is the function called and run in the script?

yes, I call the function within my script

Do you have nesteed functions within the script? Do you get any result if you add the return at the very end of the script?

I have no nested functions

Marie,
when u call $result = Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath $ps1its crucial to understand that PS1 is suposed to be a path to a scriptblock not a function. And even though your scriptblock might have a function it is a scirptblock. A scriptblock can be defined inline like this:
   $myScriptBlock= {
        if ($JobStatus -like "Running")
                {
                $result = $false
                "Gresit"
                }
            else 
                {
                $result = $true
                "Corect"
                }
        }
}

U can use it like this:
$result = Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock $myScriptBlock

whatever is expressed in that scriptblock like "Corect" in one case will be appended to $result. If there is more than one result expressed, u may access them with $result[0] or $result[1] and so on. Another thing to consider when working with scriptblocks is that they are encapsulated and therefore have no access to variables u declared outside of it. If u use $JobStatus from outside the block u will have to introduce it to the scriptblock by using  -argumentlist.
I suggest you start over with a simple application of scriptblock. Here is a tutorial [https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/invoke/][1]
If u need to figure out whats gooing on in that script or scriptblock use a transscript to write all errors and your outputs to a logfile. Put this at the beginning of your scriptblock or script:
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\transcripts\transcript0.txt"

